# Eclipse on Mac doesn't allow to downgrade (E)Git

Tags: eclipse, macos, egit

I have updated my Eclipse for Committers to version 2021-12 (For MacOS), and found out that the default Git-plugin version installed is 6.0. Since Git deprecated some features who are still crucial to me, i tried to downgrade Git version to 5.11 (the last version i know that has the requested features).

But apparently Eclipse doesn't allow to uninstall any of it's Git add-ons, which is the first step in the downgrading process.

I tried to uninstall from different menu paths, but they all lead to failure. I also tried that with "Eclipse for Java developers" (non-committers), and with older versions of Eclipse, without success.

Does anyone know what can i do?

Thanks.

[image: the "uninstall" button is in]

[image: Uninstallation from Marketplace fails]

Comment: None of this is meant as FUD. It's a fact that different Git implementations will have *different bugs* (when they do have bugs) and *a problem with implementation X in language Y* won't cause a different implementation in a different language to behave differently on its own. So it's important to isolate specifics, and installing EGit *should not* make it hard to change the CGit version.

Comment: Oh - I thought it was about downgrading *C* Git. OK, now all this makes more sense. I'll snip out all my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says in the dialog, the Git Integration is required by something else you have installed. There's little unique about the "Eclipse for Committers" download, meaning if you can't uninstall something you want to uninstall, you can still start from the bare basics and then install more into it. You should start with an SDK download from https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ and then add the versions of software you actually want to it.